# Could not locate configuration file GoogleService-Info.plist when using FirebaseApp.configure(options:)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my project I have different targets for the same app with different configurations (Production / Staging / QA). As suggested by the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application) I added a `plist` file for each trarget and initializing FirebaseApp by passing the correct configuration file in this way:

```
let configPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: NAME_OF_PLIST_FOR_CURRENT_TARGET ofType: ".plist")!
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: configPath)!
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

I also removed from my project the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file as suggested in docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#reliable-analytics) to ensure reliable Analytics reports.

When I run the app in the console I see these messages.

```
[Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS020006] Google App ID from GoogleService-Info.plist is empty. Please, define GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist for Analytics to work reliably. See
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025020] Analytics requires Google App ID from GoogleService-Info.plist. Your data may be lost. Google App ID has been changed. Original, new ID: (nil), MYAPPID
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could this configuration lead to lost Analytics? (as console message suggest)

Comment: Try to follow step 4 under "Add Firebase to your app": https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites

Comment: Do you mean "Add Firebase SDKs to your app"? I already added `'Firebase/Core'` to the project. Also, when using a single `GoogleService-Info.plist`  everything works (my app is in production already and Analytics is working).

Comment: Have you checked each configuration?   Are they all behaving exactly the same?  Based on that error message, it looks like the FirebaseOptions are not getting set properly (especially since you're not using the default file name any more).

Comment: I downloaded configuration files from Firebase Console. Also in the debugger if I check the value of `options.googleAppID` before passing `options` to `FirebaseApp.configure` I get the correct value.

Comment: I had a similar issue, so I left the original file name, I moved files into folders and set Target Memberships according to the Target. Did you try that?

Answer (score 10):

### When you use flutter:

I ran the flutter cli to add Firebase to my project, using the `flutterfire configure` command. This added the `GoogleService_Info.plist` to my project, but didn't register the file in the `.xcworkspace` file.

So I had to right-click on the `Runner`-folder in Xcode, choose `Add Files to "Runner"...`, and select the file `GoogleService_Info.plist`

Answer (score 5):

After several attempts it seemed that, despite the error messages in the console, Firebase was configured correctly.

Nonetheless I decided to adopt the solution proposed by @Micgal, thus having multiple files named `GoogleService-Info.plist` in separate filesystem directories and adding each one to the corresponding target. I can then initialize Firebase with `FirebaseApp.configure()` which works as expected without generating error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative workaround to having separate folders for `GoogleService-Info.plist` is adding additional step in Build Phases, to copy appropriate file. Just go to Targets / Build Phases and add new script by clicking on "New Run Script Phase". Script could be something like:

```
cp "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT}/${FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE}.plist" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

where `FIREBASE_CONFIG_FILE` is defined in Build Settings as User-Defined settings which has different values for various configurations. And then just calling `FirebaseApp.configure()`.

There is also a dedicated ticket on [Firebase github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230)

[image: Build Phases]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to add this needed file (GoogleService-Info.plist) to you project ressources. Open yourproject.xcworkspace in Xcode and in the **Project navigator** click right on **Ressources** folder and select 'Add files to...'.

Answer (score 0):

Select the GoogleService-Info.plist in the left pane, then uncheck/recheck the Target Membership checkbox for your project.

[image: Right panel target membership]